# Neo4j shortest path with rels in both directions

Tags: graph, neo4j, shortest-path

I have a graph set up with the function...

```
create (a:station {name:"a"}),
(b:station {name:"b"}),
(c:station {name:"c"}),
(d:station {name:"d"}),
(e:station {name:"e"}),
(f:station {name:"f"}),
(a)-[:CONNECTS_TO {time:8}]->(b),
(a)-[:CONNECTS_TO {time:4}]->(c),
(a)-[:CONNECTS_TO {time:10}]->(d),
(b)-[:CONNECTS_TO {time:3}]->(c),
(b)-[:CONNECTS_TO {time:9}]->(e),
(c)-[:CONNECTS_TO {time:40}]->(f),
(d)-[:CONNECTS_TO {time:5}]->(e),
(e)-[:CONNECTS_TO {time:3}]->(f)
```

and using the function

```
START startStation=node:node_auto_index(name = "a"), endStation=node:node_auto_index(name = "f")
MATCH p =(startStation)-[r*]->(endStation)
WITH extract(x IN rels(p)| x.time) AS Times, length(p) AS `Number of Stops`, reduce(totalTime = 0, x IN rels(p)| totalTime + x.time) AS `Total Time`, extract(x IN nodes(p)| x.name) AS Route
RETURN Route, Times, `Total Time`, `Number of Stops`
ORDER BY `Total Time`
```

and it returns the results...

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route             | Times    | Total Time | Number of Stops |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["a","d","e","f"] | [10,5,3] | 18         | 3               |
| ["a","b","e","f"] | [8,9,3]  | 20         | 3               |
| ["a","c","f"]     | [4,40]   | 44         | 2               |
| ["a","b","c","f"] | [8,3,40] | 51         | 3               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Which is fine except because it is a directed graph and there is no path from `c -> b` it doesn't return (for instance) `[a, c, b, e, f]` which is a valid path of length 4.

So, if I add the inverse paths...

```
MATCH (START)-[r:CONNECTS_TO]->(END )
CREATE UNIQUE (START)<-[:CONNECTS_TO { time:r.time }]-(END )
```

And run the query again I get... (for paths length 1..4)...

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route                 | Times        | Total Time | Number of Stops |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["a","d","e","f"]     | [10,5,3]     | 18         | 3               |
| ["a","c","b","e","f"] | [4,3,9,3]    | 19         | 4               |
| ["a","b","e","f"]     | [8,9,3]      | 20         | 3               |
| ["a","c","f"]         | [4,40]       | 44         | 2               |
| ["a","c","b","c","f"] | [4,3,3,40]   | 50         | 4               |
| ["a","c","f","e","f"] | [4,40,3,3]   | 50         | 4               |
| ["a","b","c","f"]     | [8,3,40]     | 51         | 3               |
| ["a","b","a","c","f"] | [8,8,4,40]   | 60         | 4               |
| ["a","d","a","c","f"] | [10,10,4,40] | 64         | 4               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This does include the path `[a, c, b, e, f]` but it also include `[a, c, b, c, f]` which uses `c` twice and `[a, c, f, e, f]` which uses `f` (the destination?!) twice.

Is there a way of filtering the paths so each path only includes the same node once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a filtering after the fact, but it might not be the fastest thing.

Something like this:

```
START startStation=node:node_auto_index(name = "a"), endStation=node:node_auto_index(name = "f")
MATCH p = (startStation)-[r*..4]->(endStation)

WHERE length(reduce (a=[startStation], n IN nodes(p) | CASE WHEN n IN a THEN a ELSE a + n END)) = length(nodes(p))

WITH extract(x IN rels(p)| x.time) AS Times, length(p) AS `Number of Stops`, reduce(totalTime = 0, x IN rels(p)| totalTime + x.time) AS `Total Time`, extract(x IN nodes(p)| x.name) AS Route
RETURN Route, Times, `Total Time`, `Number of Stops`
ORDER BY `Total Time`
```

I created a GraphGist with your question and answers in as an executable, live document.

See here: [Neo4j shortest path with rels in both directions](http://gist.neo4j.org/?9600617)

Comment: Thanks very much! This does what I want thanks :D BTW... from the Neo4j manual http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html the REST API methods seems to have a Dijkstra's algorithm shortest path function. Is this available in Cypher too?

Comment: Unfortunately no Dijkstra in Cypher yet. It's planned too.